# Python rewriting instead of appending

Tags: python, csv, fileappender

I have two csv files result.csv and sample.csv.

result.csv

```
M11251TH1230 
M11543TH4292 
M11435TDS144
```

sample.csv

```
M11435TDS144,STB#1,Router#1 
M11543TH4292,STB#2,Router#1 
M11509TD9937,STB#3,Router#1
M11543TH4258,STB#4,Router#1
```

I have a python script which will compare both the files  if line in result.csv matches with the first word in the line in sample.csv, then append 1 else append 0 at every line in sample.csv

It should look like M11435TDS144,STB#1,Router#1,1 and M11543TH4258,STB#4,Router#1,0 since M11543TH4258 is not found in result.csv

script.py

```
import csv
with open('result.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    result_list = []
    for row in reader:
        result_list.extend(row)


with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    sample_list = []
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] in result_list:
            sample_list.append(row + [1])
        else:
            sample_list.append(row + [0])

with open('sample.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(sample_list)
```

sample output(sample.csv)if I run the script two times

```
M11435TDS144,STB#1,Router#1,1,1 
M11543TH4292,STB#2,Router#1,1,1
M11509TD9937,STB#3,Router#1,0,0
M11543TH4258,STB#4,Router#1,0,0
```

Every time I run the script, 1's and 0's are being appended in a new column sample.csv. Is there any way every time I run the script, I can replace the appended column instead of increasing columns.

Comment: Why make life difficult? Simply change the name of the output file i.e. sample_result.csv. Then your code works. All you have to do later is process the new file rather than sample.csv.

Answer (score 0):

you write to the `sample.csv` and then you use it as input file, with the additional column. That's why you have more and more 1's and 0's in this file.
Regards, Grzegorz